# Hash join in java

Tags: java

I have two relations A and B, both with all integer attributes (A {a1,a2,a3,...} B{b1,b2,b3,..}.  How would I hash-join these two in java?  The user will pick the two joining attributes.  Do I make two hashtables and then proceed to join them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what form do your relations have? Are they in a relational database? If so, just use an SQL JOIN - the DBMS will probably do a hash join, but you don't have to care about that.

If they're not in a relational database, why not?

If some weird constraint prevents you form using the best tool for the job then yes, doing a hash join is as simple as putting each tuple into a hashtable keyed on the join attribute and then iterating over the entries of one and looking up matches in the other. *If* all your data fits into main memory, that is.

Comment: Just to clarify, I would put each relation into a hashtable and each attribute would be keyed by the join attribute. Then iterate through the each hashtable to looking for matches?

Comment: @Jack: read the wikipedia article. You only need one hashtable to contain one of the relations, then go through the other relation and look for matches to the join attribute in the hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Here his a way to do an hash-join in Java 
The best is to hash one table A with an hashmap.

```
HashMap<Sting, Object[]> hash = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
for (Object[] a : as) {
    hash.put(a.a1, a);
}
```

Then loop in B using the hash and regroup the matched.

```
ArrayList joined = new ArrayList();
for(Objec[] b : bs){
    A a = hash.get(b.b1);
    joined.add(new Object[]{a, b});
}
```

This will  work only if each element of A table has an unique a1.